# Selenium Python TimeoutException: Message: ' '

Tags: python, selenium

Im having a problem identifying what exactly is causing this timeout exception. Here is my code:

```
class EntertainmentSocialMedia(CoreTest):
def testEntertainmentTwitter(self):
    d = self.driver.getDriver()
    d.get(config.host_url + '/thewire')

    interstitial = True

    while interstitial == True:
        try:
            interstitial_link = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#interstitial-link"))
                ).click()
            interstitial = False
        except NoSuchElementException:
            interstitial = False


    print "Locating Entertainment vertical social share button"
    frame = WebDriverWait(d, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "twitter-widget-0"))
    )
```

When I try this, I get the same result.

```
class EntertainmentSocialMedia(CoreTest):
    def testEntertainmentTwitter(self):
        d = self.driver.getDriver()
        d.get(config.host_url + '/thewire')
        try:
            frame = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#interstitial-link"))
        ).click()       
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print "No Welcome ad"


        print "Locating Entertainment vertical social share button"
        frame = WebDriverWait(d, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#l"))
        )
```

I must be missing something!

Comment: Can you post a full traceback? The error indicated that either one of your `WebDriverWait(d,.....` statements did not find the element in the given time limit. With a full traceback we can tell which line it was. If I had to guess it would be the one in your try/except since `WebDriverWait` throws a `TimeoutException` not a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh that must be it! by the way, here is the full traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Desktop/Selenium-RC-Tests/tests/EntertainmentSocialMedia.py", line 23, in testEntertainmentTwitter
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#interstitial-link"))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
TimeoutException: Message: ''

Comment: Then I would be correct in assuming that is where your error is thrown. If you simply want to ignore those errors than changing your except to catch `TimeoutException` instead would be correct. I only assume so because you're trying to catch the other one already.